# jQuery AJAX function nested in AJAX output (innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use jQuery Ajax (innerHTML) to generate a listing of records from MySQL database. I would like to put a `DELETE` button next to each of these records.

Once you press the `DELETE` button, the record will be removed from database and faded away from the displayed list. Is it possible to do it - to nest another jQuery Ajax function in innerHTML output?

Please note that the `DELETE` function I use works perfectly fine with standard PHP/HTML output.

In the main php file (test1.php ) I have form to choose a time frame and once form is being submitted function bellow is generating my output in the same file:

```
<div id="display_taxation_data"></div>
```

Code responsible for generating listing:

```
function showDataLabour(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("display_taxation_data").innerHTML = "<h3>No results. Please select taxation period.</h3><hr>";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("display_taxation_data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","accounting_get_period_data_labour.php?period="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Code for accounting_get_period_data_labour.php ( set of records being generated based on previously selected time frame.)

```
echo "<tr id='record-$id'>";
echo "<td width='40'><a href='accounting_expenses_delete.php?delete=$id' class='delete'><i class='fa fa-times fa-2x' aria-hidden='true' title='Delete'></i></a></td>";
echo '</tr>';
```

And delete function that I want to trigger once button `DELETE` is pressed:

```
$(function() {
$('a.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
    console.log('idno : ' + parent);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'accounting_expenses_delete.php',
        data: 'delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
        beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},100);
        },
        success: function() {
            parent.fadeOut(100,function() {
                parent.remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

And finally short code for accounting_expenses_delete.php

```
<?
include "connectdb_mysqli.php"; 
$testdel = $_POST['delete'];
$result = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `test` WHERE id='$testdel'"); 
 ?>
```

Please let me know if you need some more information.

Looking forward to your advice or solution on how I can achieve that `DELETE` action. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is feasible but can You add code snippets from  accounting_expenses_delete.php?

Comment: no the delete code isn't relevant, the create code is. post the php code that creates the record from the ajax request.

Comment: i updated my question to make my code a little more clear

Comment: `data: 'delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),` but your `<tr>` above has no id or did you just bypass that one?

Comment: sorry @Poiz,  i try so many things - editing error, tr has id.

Comment: Take a look at one possible solution below using JQuery alone....

Comment: Yes yuh can bind ajax call on success of ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a `data-id` tag for each of the link to delete:

```
echo '<td width="40">
          <a href="#" data-id="'.$id.'" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete"></i></a>
      </td>';
```

Once this button has been clicked, it will run an Ajax request:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var elem = $(this),
        id = elem.attr('data-id'); /* GET THE ID NO. OF THE CLICKED DELETE LINK */

    $.ajax({ /* AJAX REQUEST */
        type: 'post',
        url: 'accounting_expenses_delete.php',
        data: {'delete-id': id},
        success: function() {
            elem.closest('tr').hide(200);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then for your `accounting_expenses_delete.php`:

```
include('connectdb_mysqli.php');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM test WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["delete-id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

I used [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to do the DELETE query above.

---

## Note:

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is a javascript library and the script I had provided is a jQuery, so it means you have to include first the jQuery library before your script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    /* YOUR JQUERY SCRIPT HERE */
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but where should I put AJAX request? in accounting_get_period_data_labour.php ??

Comment: @Nita - yes, provided that you also include `jQuery` in that file.

Comment: Thank you for your time but is doesn't work. Take away: data-id.

Comment: @Nita - you should tell why it did not work, like stating the error you got, from your browser's console or from the page itself.

Comment: @Nita - lets troubleshoot the problem. Try putting `console.log('test');` after the `e.preventDefault();` and inside the ajax request. It should display two `test` in your browser's console.

Comment: all the testing logs are fine in the listing creating part of code. I have them numbered so i know where is what. He just cant find that DELETE button and bind function to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114174/discussion-between-logan-wayne-and-nita).

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the value from PHP to JavaScript? If so, You may have some luck with eval() which can execute a code block that is stored in a string.

Comment: could you be so kind to provide me with some example on how that could be done. Thx.

Comment: @Nita eval is used like eval('alert("hello")'); so if your response variable contains some JavaScript you can execute it as eval(nameOfJSVar);

Answer (score 0):

You used raw Javascript for your first AJAX call to get the listings. And suddenly, you are changing to JQuery for your deletion. Why not either do both in Pure Javascript or JQuery?  I think JQuery is a little more easier. Below is a JQuery-based solution for fetching and deleting data:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function (e) {

                function showDataLabour(str) {
                    var taxDataBlock   = $("#display_taxation_data");

                    if(str == ""){
                        taxDataBlock.html("<h3>No results. Please select taxation period.</h3><hr>");
                    }else{
                        $.ajax({
                            type    : 'GET',
                            url     : 'accounting_get_period_data_labour.php?period=' + str,
                            success : function(data) {
                                if(data){
                                    taxDataBlock.html(data);
                                    var generatedData   = $(data);
                                    var deleteBtn       = generatedData.find("a.delete");
                                    // SINCE THE LISTINGS ARE GENERATED HERE,
                                    // TARGET < a class='delete'> ELEMENT(S) WITHIN THE GENERATED CONTENT
                                    // AND PASS IT AS AN ARGUMENT TO THE DELETE FUNCTION...
                                    deleteViaAjax(deleteBtn);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                function deleteViaAjax(deleteBtn){
                    deleteBtn.click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
                        console.log('idno : ' + parent);

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url : 'accounting_expenses_delete.php',
                            data: {'delete': parent.attr('id').replace('record-','')},
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},100);
                            },
                            success: function() {
                                parent.fadeOut(100,function() {
                                    parent.remove();
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response.i checked it but it doesn't work. It seems that nothing is being triggered when button is clicked on. Take away will be advice on <a> tag. Good one. ps.  I updated my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your **delete()** function use jQuery to make an ajax call. Why your **showDataLabour()** function use native XMLHttpRequest? It's better to use jQuery too :-)

You can not use:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
        // your code for delete action
    });
});
```

to bind **click** event to your delete button, because the button does not exist when the page has been loaded completely. It will be exist **AFTER** an ajax call made by showDataLabour() function has been completed.

In this situation, you can use **delegated event**. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
        // your code for delete action
    });
});
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/on/ for further information.

Comment: Is there a website where I can create a fiddle from my issue (few files and sample mysql data) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showDataExpenses(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("display_taxation_data").innerHTML = "<h3>No results. Please select taxation period.</h3><hr>";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("display_taxation_data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
     xmlhttp.open("GET","accounting_get_period_data_expenses.php?period="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var elem = $(this),
    id = elem.attr('data-id'); /* GET THE ID NO. OF THE CLICKED DELETE LINK */
    $.ajax({ /* AJAX REQUEST */
    type: 'post',
    url: 'accounting_expenses_delete.php',
    data: {'delete-id': id},
    success: function() {
        elem.closest('tr').hide(200);
    }
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Working script. Important is to load jQuery first